# Can TFS work with 3rd party SCM systems like Git?

Tags: tfs

I generally like the project management / ALM features of TFS but don't like the version control part of it (even SVN takes more modern approach to SCM, not to mention all those distributed SCMs like Git or Mercurial).

So the question is, can the SCM part of TFS somehow be "ignored" and SVN or Git used instead while keeping all the other nicer TFS things like issue tracker, Scrum project management template, Visual Studio integration etc?

(I doubt it but wanted to ask.)

Comment: What exactly makes you think there's a tie between TFS version control and the rest of the product? What sorts of problems would you expect?

Comment: I don't have hands-on experience with TFS, I've just seen things like gated check-ins, source code <-> issue tracker links etc. always demonstrated with the built-in source control provider, never with Git or SVN.

Comment: Yeah, none of those things can possibly work with a different source control system. But there's no reason you can't use the the other features.

Answer (score 5):

There's [git-tfs](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs). Basically you use git for your daily regular work and then push changes to your local working copy from tfs and commit from there. It uses scripts to do the magic.

A co-worker of mine used git-tfs for several months and over all I think he liked the workflow of it, but ultimately stopped using it because basically he was using git AND tfs, so it was a bit of an overhead as far as time goes.

Comment: I'm also a little worried that tfs-git would add unnecessary overhead. I don't want to store source codes in TFS, I'd just like to use its ALM features and have the repository completely separate if possible. I think that FogBugz, Assembla and other online PM tools can work like that - they let you host your repository on, say, GitHub but still offer issue tracker, collaboration features etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you couldn't use the work item tracking in TFS along side a separate SCM.

There are a few features that integrate WIT with SCM, like associating work items to checkins and I believe some of the test impact stuff.

You would also miss out on all the Team Build features (automated builds on checking, gated checkins etc) - unless you heavily customize the Build Template and write some helper applications to trigger builds, but even then you won't get a few of the features (gated checkins).

Without builds then Test and Lab management functionality would be fairly restricted too.

Comment: Exactly, I wouldn't like to lose all the other interesting features which unfortunately seem to be tightly coupled to Source Control, Build etc.

Comment: That's not necessarily a fault with TFS, you can't really expect to be able to get all the features of a product when you're not using the product. It's like switching from IE to Firefox/Chrome then blaming Microsoft that active-x doesn't work in those browsers.  You're weighing up two pieces of software, the advantages of using TFS is all the integration, the advantages of SVN/Git are other things.

Comment: There are solutions like Assembla, JIRA etc. that also try to provide ALM features while still being able to work with SVN, Git or Mercurial. So it kind of is a "fault" of TFS that it is tightly coupled to a particular source control implementation. But OK, that's how it is, I just wanted to make sure and will be looking elsewhere.